# What does an infinite AIC mean and what can be done about it?

Tags: r, regression, aic, stepwise-regression

I have a question about performing stepwise regression. I realize that there are issues with using stepwise methods, but I have about 30 or so predictors and have constructed an `lm` object.

```
m1 <- lm(LEADSforester ~ . , data=dat)
m2 <- lm(LEADSforester ~ 1 , data=dat)
step(m1, m2, direction = "backward")
```

However, when I run the following line of code, I get an error message.

```
backBIC <- step(m1, direction="backward", data=dat)

Error in step(m1, direction = "backward") : 
  AIC is -infinity for this model, so 'step' cannot proceed
```

The same problem occurs when I run the following:

```
m1 = lm(LEADS ~ ED + Fa + Pu + New + Gr + Vol + Dur + Boun + Visit + views + Nw + 
                Uniq + sits, data=dat)
step(m1, direction="backward")

Error in step(m1, direction = "backward") : 
  AIC is -infinity for this model, so 'step' cannot proceed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `nrow(dat)` say - i.e. how many observations do you have?

Comment: @gung I think this may actually contain an underlying statistical problem, though the OP may not realize it. ATMathew: AIC is -infinity when the fit is perfect (has no error), because there's a $\log(s^2)$ term.

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b (and therefore +1 to the question).

Comment: ATMathew - it would probably help other people find the cause of their problem if your title referred to the AIC being $-\infty$ rather than to R or the stepwise procedure (neither of which I'd think are specifically related to the direct cause of the problem).

Comment: @GavinSimpson 43

Comment: Hmm... You are using 13 parameters (and therefore $2^{13}-1$, which is over 8000, models) to fit only 43 observations.  Search our site for [overfitting](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=overfitting) for some advice about that.

Comment: Following on @whuber 's comment, you should probably be modeling only 1 independent variable at a time. Either that, or collect a lot more data.

Comment: AIC = 2k - 2*log(L). K is the number of parameters in the model and L is the maximized value of the likelihood function. If AIC is infinite you have L << 1. In case of a least squares this can only happen if variance is zero. Probably you have one or a set of  covariates that together are perfectly collinear with the outcome ... In other words, there is nothing left in the residuals.

Comment: @mmgm why you did not to writing this comment as an answer elaborating a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Forward feature selection?

```
min.model <- lm(y ~ 1, data=dat)
fwd.model <- step(min.model, direction = "forward", scope = (~ x1 + x2 + ... xn))
```

This way the model will only add predictors until it can.