# Error trying to reduce my data dimentions

Tags: r, pca, feature-selection, factor-analysis

I'm trying to produce a linear regression model, but I only have 25 observations and 34 predictors.

I'm trying feature selection,

```
library(MASS)
full.m <- lm(fmla, data=mydata)
fsel.m <- step(full.m, direction = "both")
```

but I get this error,

```
Error in step(full.m, direction = "both") : 
  AIC is -infinity for this model, so 'step' cannot proceed
```

Well, then I tried PCA and factor analysis but I get this weird image from PCA.

```
r <- prcomp(formula=pca.fmla, mydata, scale=FALSE)
```

[image]

In factor analysis,

```
f <- factanal(x=pca.fmla, mydata, factors=2)
```

I get,

```
Error in solve.default(cv) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.09137e-18
```

Any help please?

EDIT: I can answer this.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68087 is also a duplicate, even though it, too, has no answer. However, I believe you will find useful information in the comments posted there.

Comment: I have a solution, but why can't I answer then my question?

Comment: Why not answer one of the duplicate questions?